# Cannot find an Excel chart to suit my needs

Tags: excel, charts, excel-2007

First of all, sorry for this rather odd request. I was not able to find something suitable for several hours, neither do I actually have a concise description that I can use to look for solutions (language barrier be damned). I hope this isn't inappropriate.

---

I need to create a chart that reflects a balance (inflow vs outflow) that looks like the example below. The overall size needs to be fixed and only the green/red column is allowed to change its size based on the input values.
For clarification, these are not 2 separate charts but 2 of the possible outcomes it should be able to display.

Can someone please help me out with an idea of what to look at or at least what to call my problem so I can keep on searching?

[image: Mockup chart]

Comment: try 100% stacked bar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set up your data and bar chart as shown. When the chart is finished you can slide it over B5:E6 to hide the hard work.

[image: construction of requested chart]

The data value of interest is entered in B3. Formulas in other cells are:

- B6:  =MIN(0,B3)
- C6:  =-10-B6
- D6:  =MAX(0,B3)
- E6:  =10-D6

Chart 1: Select B5:E6 and insert a stacked bar chart.

Chart 2: Switch Rows and Columns.

Chart 3: Clean up (no axis labels, no gridlines, dark gray vertical axis line, bar series gap width 100)

Chart 4: Format the two Gray series with gray fill, and Red and Green with Red and Green fill. Also add data labels to Red and Green series, showing default of Y Values. Use these custom number formats to show only values of interest:

- Green:  +General;;;
- Red:  ;–General;;

Here is how the chart looks with sample values of +2 and -5:

[image: display of requested chart]

Comment: Thank you for the specific answer Jon! (wow, I'm honored, I have your blog bookmarked :-)) Especially the custom number formatting is excellent and will save me some tricky VBA workarounds to hide the labels when 0. Is there a way to stretch the bar to fit the drawing canvas without using fixed x-axis values?

Comment: @Ben - Not sure what you mean? The plot area of the chart (the inner rectangle) can be stretched almost to the extent of the chart.

Comment: Oh my, I completely forgot about that possibility. Thanks for pointing that out. It's now working according to required specifications.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm reading your question correctly, the bar chart might be an option.  After creating a basic "Bar chart", I went to "Format Data Series" (via right click on chart columns) and in "Fill" menu selected "Invert if negative" check box, then set the colors to green and red in that same window. I am not sure what you mean by keeping "overall size fixed". Is it something like a total?

Sorry, I couldn't post the picture cause my rep level isn't high enough. Hope this helps.

Comment: I meant that the grey area should maintain the same size. The coloured bars can expand and shrink but the overall size of the diagram, the grey areas, should stay as they are so I don't need to reposition the chart as it changes.

Comment: If grey area represents totals and your data is organized as values going across (horizontally) and totals (representing grey) right under, you can do "Stacked Bar" chart. With the chart created, go to "Format Data Series" -> Fill check "Invert if Negative" checkbox and click on Solid Fill to choose Green and Red. To only display values on bars (not the labels), right click on vertical axis -> Axis Options, in Axis Labels drop down choose None. Hope that's what you're looking for!

Comment: The Stacked Bar graph did the trick! I had to add 4 stacked bars and a fixed x-axis from -10 to 10. If you then grey out the outer stacks and only color one of the other stacks (green for inflow, red for outflow) and adjust the length of the corresponding grey bar so they add up to the overall length of -10/+10, it looks just like in the picture I uploaded.